# Need to wait in AsynkTask a event in broadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

For some reasons, i need to call a method, we will name it foo(), with return me some_data (byte[]).

In this function, i call an asynctask which return me my some_data.
But, in this aynctask, i have to wait an event from broadcastReceiver to continue the process.

Because i need return foo() not asynchronously, i have to call my asynktask like this :

```
byte[] some_data = myTask.execute().get();
return some_data;
```

But, when i use get(), this freeze the main Thread, and in this main Thread, i have my BroadcastReceiver :

```
    private final BroadcastReceiver mRecv = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ReaderHelper.BROADCAST_WRITE_DATA)) {
            final String dataReceive = intent.getStringExtra("log");
            //some process
            dataReceived = true;
        }
    }
};
```

So, my asynkTask don't want anymore because i wait for dataReceived = true to continue :

```
    @Override
    protected byte[] doInBackground(Object... voids) {
        for (Pair<Integer, Integer> sector : sectorToRead) {
            sendBytes(sector.first, sector.second);
            waitingReceive();
            //todo rajouter relance commande si trop d'echec ?
        }

        //some process and return finalData
        return finalData;
    }
```

The code of my function waitingReceive :

```
    private void waitingReceive() {
    while (!dataReceived) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    dataReceived = false;
}
```

So, waintingReceive() start an infinite loop because i use asyntask.execute.get() and i freez my main thread and i guess, the callback in broadcastReceiver.

How i can proceed ? Thanks

Comment: I think you have to rethink your architecture here. Basically you want to use an asynctask in a non-asynchrous way (i.e. waiting for it to finish - thereby blocking the main thread with myTask.execute().get();). In general to block the main thread waiting for a result is a bad idea in Android.

Comment: I'm agree with you, but the fact is, the function foo() was use in a library already developed in java (and can be use in Android project or just java project).
So, this library call my function like this :

    byte[] dataNeed = myIml.foo();
    //process

Answer (score 1):

```
never use Thread.sleep(10) and u can use handler like wise

 Handler handler;
    Runnable runnable;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                if (dataReceived)
                {
                    cancelHandler();
                }
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);
    }

    public void cancelHandler()
    {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }
```